# What is difference between Response.Redirect("http://url") and Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://url")?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, httpwebresponse

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC3 with C#.

What is difference between `Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");` and `Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://www.google.com");`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the first will replace the response with a redirection page and end the execution, while the second will just write the text to the response stream and continue with creating the rest of the page.

Comment: Good answer, +1. In addition to that I would say that none of them should be used in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Why you say that none of them should be used in ASP.net MVC? Any specific reason behind this?

Comment: @Krunal: Because in MVC you should return a `RedirectResult` from the method in your controller to do a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect()` sets an HTTP 302 header along with the URL to be redirected to.

`Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://www.google.com");` will write that string to the response body, as in that redirect text would be appended to the HTML of your web page.

Answer (score 0):

This will create the correct full HTTP Header for you:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

You have the ability to set or change some paramters for the HTTP Header.

```
HttpResponse Class
```

e.g set HTTP Status Code 404 or 500 or in your case 302 for redirect.

e.g set the HTTP Mime-type for jpg

Will write into the Body in your response..like a string output

```
Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods in question are quite self explanatory :)

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

The `Redirect` will redirect you to another page, in the case it will take you to [Google's](http://www.google.com) home page.

```
Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://www.google.com");
```

The `Write` method will write a string of text to the web page.  In this case it will write the text `"REDIRECT=http://www.google.com"` to your web page.

Play around with these 2 methods in your web project and see what happens.